# TabHost on Android crashes the app

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am trying to use TabHost for the first time and I have some issues.
Any idea why this does not work?

activity_dashboard.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app.DashboardActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <Button android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app.main">


    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</FrameLayout>
```

and the java...:
DashboardActivity.java

```
package ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app;
import ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app.util.SystemUiHider;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        final Button blogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dummy_button);
        blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, main.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast mytoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wow it works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mytoast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and
main.java

```
package ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            tabHost.setup();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button in the first activity, I should see the second activity with the tabHost, but all I get is a message saying "Unfortunately, testtabapp stopped working"

I did not continue with the setting up of the tabhost because it gives the same message, so I stripped the code up to the point where it stops working

What am I doing wrong?

(PS.: I am using Android Studio)
And I tried to replace the id of the TabHost but the same result comes up, even in LogCat.
I do not understand the problem. Cand you test it on your environment and see if you get the same result?

After replacing the id inside the layout for the TabHost, the app does not crash, however the error in LogCat says the same as before. It still complains about tabHost ID but no crashing.

Also, if I want to continue the code by adding the tabs, the application crashes with the same LogCat ?!?!?! That complains about the tabHost id but without stopping the app.

So code added:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            Toast mytoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's greater than HONEYCOMB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mytoast.show();

            TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


            TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("TabClienti");
            TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("TabVizite");
            TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("TabRaportZi");
            TabHost.TabSpec tab4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("TabSync");

        // Set the Tab name and Activity
        // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
            tab1.setIndicator("Clientii");
            tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,ListClientiTab.class));

            tab2.setIndicator("Vizitele");
            tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,ListViziteTab.class));

            tab3.setIndicator("Raport zi");
            tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,RaportZiTab.class));

            tab4.setIndicator("Sincronizare");
            tab4.setContent(new Intent(this, SyncTab.class));

        /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
            tabHost.addTab(tab1);
            tabHost.addTab(tab2);
            tabHost.addTab(tab3);
            tabHost.addTab(tab4);
            tabHost.setup();
```

(this was added to the onCreate of the activity that holds the TabHost in it's layout.)

And the LogCat for this code (I removed the errors from the above LogCat so below it only shows what happens when I click the button):

```
03-05 18:13:44.709    1460-1460/ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-05 18:13:44.709    1460-1460/ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
03-05 18:13:44.749    1460-1460/ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app/ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:232)
            at ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app.main.onCreate(main.java:45)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 18:13:47.178    1460-1460/ro.softwarex.bellaapp.testtabhost.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1460 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: I did. Please check it above

Comment: indicate line 232 @ TabHost

Comment: I do not get it... I do not have 232 lines in my code, and I do not have a TabHost java file. It probably is from the SDK. Anyway I solved my second problem (adding Tabs) by using a deprecated approach for the TabHost: extending TabActivity instead of Activity and using a function to get the TabHost instead of finding it based on the ID. So I solved two problems with one stone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the naming of your `TabHost`. You named it:

```
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
```

But when you create you `Activity` file, you're looking for:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

Which is not the same as you have. Your `TabHost` should be named this way:

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

Comment: Wow... that solved it. But still, what is the meaning of this? Even after I did this, the error in LogCat remains. I will post the LogCat next

Comment: I am posting the second LogCat up in the question because it's too long for a comment

Comment: You have still the same problem: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'`. That's the `id` you have to grant it, if not, it will keep crashing.

Comment: I changed the id inside the XML. Now it is: 
        `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` and inside the activity I call it like this: `TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);`  but the errors remain the same. LogCat still complains about the ID, but the app works, until I try to change the code and add the tabs. When I do that, app crashes (I pasted the LogCat in the question). I removed the original LogCat due to limitations on characters number...

Comment: Which is right now the line 45 of your main.java file?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this as an answer so other people can use it as solution. However I will accept nKn's answer as he was the most helpfull in the direction of solving the initial problem.

So the solution I found is to:

replace `public class main extends Activity {`

with `public class main extends TabActivity {`

(TabActivity has a strikethrough line in my editor, saying it's deprecated)

and then, for accessing the tabHost, instead of doing this:

`TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);...`

I did this:

`TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("clientii").setIndicator(
       "TAB clienti").setContent(new Intent(this,ListClientiTab.class)));`

So, like this, I can see the activity with the TABS, and the app does not crash.
I hate this kind of problems that can only be solved (quickly) by using deprecated aproaches.